Movie where guy beats someone with handful of car antennas
What is the name of the movie where a tough white guy is angry at another white guy, and he is walking in the city to meet him, and on the way, he tears off car antennas from parked cars, and when he sees the other guy, he whips him with the fistful of car antennas?
American production. Probably 1975 - 1995 era. Genre is a tough guy movie: subdued drama by today’s standards filled with tough characters like low level gangsters or undercover cops, but movies like Roadhouse and Rocky also fit this category. It has a serious tone.
I recall no plot details or any more details other than this vivid scene. I’ve been watching movies like Night Moves with Gene Hackman and Robert Altman’s The Long Goodbye to find this scene, but no luck. So sadly, you’d probably have to have seen this movie and been as struck by this scene as I was to help me out.
This could also be an episode of Miami Vice or Hill Street Blues now that I think about it but no searches turn up anything from the show.
I just found out Rumble In The Bronx has a similar scene, but that scene with Jackie Chan is humorous as is that entire movie. It is an action comedy. The film I’m looking is more serious, and has no Wu Shu or Asian martial arts.

You provided release year and country of origin. Nice! However, it lacks plot details? Try adding any more plot details you can remember.

This rings a bell.... will be interested to see the final answer.
